# Should I accept an answer when there's no one objectively correct answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Suppose I ask a question which for one reason or another might have multiple valid answers. Maybe it's subjective, maybe it's a problem that could have multiple solutions, maybe there are just different ways to explain the same idea. I get some answers, and one is definitely the most helpful or useful to me, among other good answers. Should I accept it? Or is that bad, because I'd be declaring it to be the one true correct answer?

Note that I'm asking this in the context of StackExchange as a whole, where this is a more common occurrence than on SO. For example, on cooking, a lot of questions can have multiple good answers. Also, I know this is a historically contentious topic, but I'm looking for fresher answers, not pointers to questions from years ago, when we didn't know what to do with subjective questions and didn't have so many diverse sites.

Comment: @Joe Thanks, I didn't find that one. It feels a little different, focusing on there being multiple *correct* answers, while I was trying to include when it's hard to say if an answer is correct per se, but I do agree that the answers apply (as does [a lot of the accepting answers faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/133299)).

Answer (score 4):

Accepting an answer means that you feel an answer was specifically helpful to you, the asker.  There may not be one true answer, but even if there is, that's what voting is for and why it's distinct from the green checkmark.  Let the community figure out what the overall 'best' answer is by voting - and add your two cents, which is slightly more valuable than anyone else's (since you asked the question), with the checkmark.